# Query optimization in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-tuning, query-tuning

```
SELECT 
    T2.Entity1Id, T1.Entity1Id  
FROM 
    T1  
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.c2 = T2.c2 AND T1.c1 = T2.c1 AND T1.c3 = 1
WHERE 
    ((T1.c1 = 123 ) OR (T2.c1 = 123))  
    AND (T1.c3 = 1 OR T1.c3 IS NULL)
```

Above query is taking 12 seconds in SQL Server 2014, any idea to tune the query? There are indexes on C1,C2,C3 columns.

Observation: in the above query, when I remove a condition from OR (i.e.

```
SELECT  
    T2.Entity1Id, T1.Entity1Id  
FROM 
    T1  
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.c2 = T2.c2 AND T1.c1 = T2.c1  AND T1.c3 = 1
WHERE 
    (T1.c1 = 123) AND (T1.c3 = 1 OR T1.c3 IS NULL)
```

then it's returning results in 0 seconds.

Each table has around 500'000 records.

Comment: *lakhs* - please use **internationally known** units of measure - thousand, million, billion ..... also: can you please show us the graphical **execution plan** for the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the final condition `(T1.c3 = 1 OR T1.c3 IS NULL)` is redundant.  Given the `join` condition, these are the only possible values.  So, the query is:

```
SELECT T2.Entity1Id, T1.Entity1Id  
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.c2 = T2.c2 AND T1.c1 = T2.c1  AND T1.c3 = 1
WHERE (T1.c1 = 123 ) OR (T2.c1 = 123)
```

If this doesn't have good performance, consider breaking this into two queries:

```
SELECT T2.Entity1Id, T1.Entity1Id  
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.c2 = T2.c2 AND T1.c1 = T2.c1  AND T1.c3 = 1
WHERE T1.c1 = 123
UNION 
SELECT T2.Entity1Id, T1.Entity1Id  
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN
     T1
     ON T1.c2 = T2.c2 AND T1.c1 = T2.c1  AND T1.c3 = 1
WHERE T2.c1 = 123
```

Sometimes, the optimization of the separate subqueries is much better than the optimization for the `full outer join`.

Comment: 1st solution is not having  any performance improvement.
But the second one is working with few changes. Thank you.